# How can I make the cursor go back and forth around the block keywords?

Tags: vim

I am at present writing a syntax file in VIM for the script language I use, which isn't a generic language like c.

One of the block syntaxes is the do..loop structure as below:

```
DO
    blah blah blah
LOOP times, label
```

I wonder that if there is a way for me to make the cursor go back and forth around DO and LOOP like in c I press % then the cursor moves during "{" and "}".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`matchit`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin to define additional pairs of block start and end keywords to jump to with `%`. For your case something like

```
:let b:match_words = '\<DO\>:\<LOOP\>'
```

should work. To keep your setup tidy you should define this in an new [filetype plugin](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype).
The `matchit`  documentation has an extra chapter `|matchit-newlang|` devoted to this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, I will try it. But i want to know that whether it is related with syntax file? In another word, how could c make sense even without the matchit plugin?

Comment: There are some built-in defaults http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%